# Processing two CSV files in parallel

Tags: python, csv

I have to csv files and I need to process them in parallel, like this:

```
import csv
with open(f1) as s1, open(f2) as s2:
    for v1 in csv.reader(s1), v2 in csv.reader(s2):
        assert v1[0] == v2[0]
        myfunc(v1[1:],v2[1:])
```

Alas, it appears that I cannot do `for a in b, c in d`:

```
NameError: global name 'v2' is not defined
```

I guess I can do something like

```
with open(f1) as s1, open(f2) as s2:
    r1 = csv.reader(s1)
    r2 = csv.reader(s2)
    while True:
        try:
            v1 = r1.next()
        except StopIteration:
            v1 = None
        try:
            v2 = r2.next()
        except StopIteration:
            v2 = None
        if (not v1) and (not v2):
            break
        assert v1 and v2
        assert v1[0] == v2[0]
        myfunc(v1[1:],v2[1:])
```

but it does not look pretty.

So, what are my other options? (I do *not* want to use [`paste`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_%28Unix%29)).

Comment: Try `for v1, v2 in zip(csv.reader(s1), csv.reader(s2))`

Comment: To add to @ColonelThirtyTwo you might also want to use `itertools.izip_longest` if the two csv files have uneven lines.

Comment: Or use `itertools.izip()` if the two files are the same length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume these files:

1.csv:

```
Mark Smith
Bobby Brown
Sue Miller
Jenny Igotit
```

2.csv:

```
555-1234
555-9876
555-6743
867-5309
```

You can use izip:

```
fn1, fn2='/tmp/1.csv', '/tmp/2.csv'

import csv
from itertools import izip

with open(fn1) as f1, open(fn2) as f2:
    r1=csv.reader(f1)
    r2=csv.reader(f2)
    for v1, v2 in izip(r1, r2):
        print v1, v2
```

Prints:

```
['Mark Smith'] ['555-1234']
['Bobby Brown'] ['555-9876']
['Sue Miller'] ['555-6743']
['Jenny Igotit'] ['867-5309']
```

If you potentially have uneven file lengths, use izip_longest:

```
import csv

from itertools import izip_longest

with open(fn1) as f1, open(fn2) as f2:
    r1=csv.reader(f1)
    r2=csv.reader(f2)
    for v1, v2 in izip_longest(r1, r2):
        print v1, v2
```

After removing one line from `2.csv`, prints:

```
['Mark Smith'] ['555-1234']
['Bobby Brown'] ['555-9876']
['Sue Miller'] ['555-6743']
['Jenny Igotit'] None
```

Comment: Using zip will read all the rows into a list.  itertools.izip is a good replacement.  This doesn't apply to izip_longest.
It's a good idea to open the files in 'rb' mode explicitly for cross platform compatibility.